# Mootools setting up Event on for loop

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a problem concerning Mootools event-handling...

having a situation you have a loop and for each cycle creating an div and attaching an event on it. It always takes the value of the last cycle of the loop.

Like:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
 var el = new Element('div').inject($(document.root));
 el.addEvent('click',function() {
  alert(i); 
 });
}
```

All Elements will alert '10'. What I want is to have every new element counting +1.
Frist=0, second=1, ...

Hope someone understands what I mean.
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a closure to encapsulate the iterator at the time of adding into a local variable:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var el = new Element('div').inject($(document.root));
    (function(i){    
        el.addEvent('click',function() {
            alert(i); 
        });
    }(i));
}
```

school of thought says you should not create functions in a loop.

other things you can do is pass the iterator to the constructor and keep it in storage:

```
var el = new Element('div').store('index', i).inject(document.body);
...
click: function(){
    console.log(this.retrieve('index'));        
}
```

you can also use a `.each` which automatically does an iterator for you:

```
var a = new Array(10);
a.forEach(function(item, index){
    new Element('div', {
        events: {
            click: function(){
                alert(index);
            }
        }
    }).inject(document.body);
});
```

you could bind it to the callback also... many many patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, not sure if it fits what you want.

Check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99Kdt/)

JS/Mootools:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
 var el = new Element('div', {onclick: 'alert('+i+')',text:i}).inject(document.body);
}
```